# D3js Force Link label's not showing

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add link labels to our forced d3js layout, based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2926502).

My issue is that I don't see these labels, and I am not able to find the problem. I just add the code lines for labels hope anybody can help.

I add most code parts that are used for that, not all code parts are included.

Thanks

```js
function xpos(s, t) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(t.y - s.y, t.x - s.x);
  return 30 * Math.cos(angle) + s.x;
};

// from example with link labels http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2926502
function ypos(s, t) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(t.y - s.y, t.x - s.x);
  return 30 * Math.sin(angle) + s.y;
};

// init drawing
function init_drawing(json) {

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 600)
    .attr("class", "graph-svg-component");

  // Create links based on ID's instead of Index's
  var edges = [];
  json.links.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.source;
      })[0],
      targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.target;
      })[0];

    edges.push({
      source: sourceNode,
      target: targetNode,
      is_switch_connection: e.is_switch_connection,
      class: e.class,
      port: e.port,
      intf_name: e.intf_name
    });
  });

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.1)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-700)
    .size([800, 600])
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(edges)
    .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(edges)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.class
    });

  // Append link text for source, from example
  var aEnd = link.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'aEnd')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d) {
      return "text aEnd";
    });

  // Append link text for target, from example
  var zEnd = link.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'zEnd')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d) {
      return "text zEnd";
    });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    // from example
    aEnd.attr('x', function(d) {
        return xpos(d.source, d.target);
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return ypos(d.source, d.target);
      });

    // from example
    zEnd.attr('x', function(d) {
        return xpos(d.target, d.source);
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return ypos(d.target, d.source);
      });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  });
}

var topo = {};
topo.nodes = [{
    'name': 'Node 1'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Node 2'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Node 3'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Node 4'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Node 5'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Node 6'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Node 7'
  }
];
topo.links = [{
    'a': ['Node 1', 'one'],
    'z': ['Node 2', 'two']
  },
  {
    'a': ['Node 2', 'three'],
    'z': ['Node 3', 'four']
  },
  {
    'a': ['Node 2', 'five'],
    'z': ['Node 4', 'six']
  },
  {
    'a': ['Node 1', 'seven'],
    'z': ['Node 5', 'eight']
  },
  {
    'a': ['Node 1', 'nine'],
    'z': ['Node 6', 'ten']
  },
  {
    'a': ['Node 1', 'eleven'],
    'z': ['Node 7', 'twelve']
  }
];

init_drawing(topo);
```

```css
.node {
  fill: #88f;
  stroke: #44a;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.aEnd,
.zEnd {
  fill: #444;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

.default {
  stroke: #fbb;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.outline {
  stroke: #844;
  stroke-width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add `<text>` nodes as children to `<line>` nodes. The only nodes that can be children of shape nodes are `<title>`s, because they don't show up.

For any other nodes, you must use a `<g>` instead. Also, your nodes were actually `<g>`s, I've made them `<circle>`s. I think that might just be for the sake of this example, though.

```js
function xpos(s, t) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(t.y - s.y, t.x - s.x);
  return 30 * Math.cos(angle) + s.x;
};

function ypos(s, t) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(t.y - s.y, t.x - s.x);
  return 30 * Math.sin(angle) + s.y;
};

function init_drawing(json) {
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 600)
    .attr("class", "graph-svg-component");

  // Create links based on ID's instead of Index's
  var edges = [];
  json.links.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.source;
      })[0],
      targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.target;
      })[0];

    edges.push({
      source: sourceNode,
      target: targetNode,
      class: e.class
    });
  });

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.1)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-700)
    .size([800, 600])
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(edges)
    .start();

  var linkGroup = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(edges)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "line");

  var link = linkGroup.append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.class;
    });

  // Append link text for source, from example
  var aEnd = linkGroup.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'aEnd')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d) {
      return "text aEnd";
    });

  // Append link text for target, from example
  var zEnd = linkGroup.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'zEnd')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d) {
      return "text zEnd";
    });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .call(force.drag);

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    // from example
    aEnd.attr('x', function(d) {
        return xpos(d.source, d.target);
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return ypos(d.source, d.target);
      });

    // from example
    zEnd.attr('x', function(d) {
        return xpos(d.target, d.source);
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return ypos(d.target, d.source);
      });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  });
}

var topo = {
  nodes: [{
      id: 'Node 1',
    },
    {
      id: 'Node 2',
    },
    {
      id: 'Node 3',
    },
    {
      id: 'Node 4',
    },
    {
      id: 'Node 5',
    },
    {
      id: 'Node 6',
    },
    {
      id: 'Node 7',
    },
  ],
  links: [{
      source: 'Node 1',
      target: 'Node 2',
    },
    {
      source: 'Node 2',
      target: 'Node 3',
    },
    {
      source: 'Node 2',
      target: 'Node 4',
    },
    {
      source: 'Node 1',
      target: 'Node 5',
    },
    {
      source: 'Node 1',
      target: 'Node 6',
    },
    {
      source: 'Node 1',
      target: 'Node 7',
    },
  ],
};

init_drawing(topo);
```

```css
.node {
  fill: #88f;
  stroke: #44a;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.aEnd,
.zEnd {
  fill: #444;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

line {
  stroke: #fbb;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```